# How do you place an SKSpriteNode at a given length of a path?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I would like to animate sprites along the one path but have them each start from different locations along that path.

Does anyone know if there is a time offset function anywhere?  I have looked but cant find one.

Thanks,
Macro

Comment: Well you could move it along the path to where you want it and then make it visible using the `hidden` property

Comment: Santa, how do you move it only part of the way along the path?

Comment: @Marco It is hard to move it to a precise position. You can use a timer (to make it move for a certain period of time), and then set its `speed` to 0. However, you cannot control the number of frames per second (as it's movement is on a per frame basis, you cannot control where it will end up using that method)

Comment: @Santa Claus, so you are saying that you can set the speed and the duration of an action but not the start time directly?

Comment: I think so. I have not fully explored the documentation.